Is there a simple expression for $\mathbb{E}[\max(a_1+b_1X_1, \ldots, a_n+b_nX_n)]$
Let us consider $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ iid with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Is there a simple expression for  $\mathbb{E}[\max(a_1+b_1X_1, \ldots, a_n+b_nX_n)]$?
Are there specific distributions for which there is a simple expression?

What do you mean by “simple expression”?

simple means closed-form as a function of the a_i and b_i.

Perhaps you can express this expected value by
$\int_\mathbb{R}yf_Y(y)dy$ where $f_Y(y)$ is defined in this answer.

I believe there is no "simple expression".  For more information, perhaps look for the topic "order statistics".
